# php http authentication: ask for password every time website is loaded?

Tags: php, http, authentication, http-authentication, basic-authentication

my question is:

how can i do in php, that EVERY TIME a website is loaded it asks for the http authentication and not just the first time?

Comment: Are you going to manage an https request?

Comment: would not that pissed your user very much?

Comment: @ajreal it's not for the user! it's for me and it's just 1 page with links! i want to enter the admin website on public computers, so i just whanted to make sure!

Comment: as long your password prompt is in `http`, is sending plain-text, so you can ignore the security issue at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

The browser provides authentication, and you have absolutely no control over it.  You cannot use this method for what you are asking, you must use another.

Technically speaking, your script shouldn't be allowing access to the resource if the browser doesn't provide proper credentials.  The browser provides credentials for each resource accessed.  But, the user will only be prompted once per browser usage session, generally.

You can read about it here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#100396

Comment: thank you for your nice and quick response! 1 more question: when i close and then open the browser, a new usage  session starts?

Comment: Usually. Please file new questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change the password and/or username and/or authentication realm. The browser decides to store the password, so there's probably not much else you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP already does this! However, people's browsers will cache their username/password input and provide it automatically throughout that session. This is to save the users getting horrifically annoyed. You have no control over this behaviour.

Perhaps you might consider an alternative authorisation approach, though I can't think of one that would reliably perform as you desire. Security over HTTP is pretty useless anyway so you might as well not bother.